# Is there a way to make system restore monitor files not otherwise monitored? [windows]

Tags: deployment, vbscript, operating-system, installation, restore

I'm using a VBS script to create a restore point every time a user uses the installer to install an update of my program, so if anything happens and the update fails, the user can easily rollback their system and still have the old version of the program.

The problem is .css, .txt, .js, .html and a bunch of other files aren't monitored by system restore, so these aren't brought back to their previous states (but my .DLLs and other tracked files are).

My question is, is there a way to force system restore to include unmonitored files or include everything in the program files folder?